# can we submit PDF form without Submit button?

Tags: pdf, pdf-form

can we submit PDF form without Submit button?
Any javascript code/other alternate is available?
Currently I have PDF form without Submit button.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or you will continue to be down-voted.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a trigger to submit.

PDF/Acrobat has a series of possible triggers, such as Button, but you might look at links or bookmarks.